# Como eu faço para que cada linha da minha matriz armazene uma substring?

Tags: c

Suponhamos que o usuário digitasse: Eu sou muito lindo

Cada linha da Matriz armazenaria uma substring ficando assim:

- Eu
- sou
- muito
- lindo

Comment: Uma possibilidade é você definir um array de ponteiros para char e alocar memória dinamicamente pra armazenar cada string e apontar por cada elemento do array. Pesquise pela função strtok (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html).

Answer (score 1):

- 1) Defina a quantidade de palavras que você deseja ler para a matriz.
- 2) Crie um char** e use malloc passando como o parâmetro o tamanho de intptr_t * número de palavras que você deseja ler
- 3) Crie um char[N] onde N é o número de letras máximo de letras em uma única palavra
- 4) Crie um laço para a leitura dos valores em cada iteração (Número das palavras que você quer ler), armazene a palavra na variável do passo 3
- 5) Realize um malloc na variável do passo 2 para cada palavra, indexando-a na variável de iteração do loop. Neste malloc você irá usar o tamanho da palavra lida (strlen) + 1 (NUL Byte)
- 6) Utilize a função strcpy para passar o buffer lido (variável do passo 3) para a matriz (variável do passo 2)

Não se esqueça depois de utilizar o free() para liberar memória.